# .NET Entity Framework query with 2 joins

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I am an Entity Framework (actual version 6) newbie and try to do some queries.

My database looks similiar to this:

[image]

I tried a query (which is not correct) like:

```
 Dim products = db.Product.Include(Function(p) p.Status).Include(Function(p) p.Status.StatusTranslations).AsExpandable().Where(predicate).Where(Function(p) p.Status.StatusTranslations.Language.Equals("en-Us"))
```

where AsExpandable() is a function from the [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx).

This is what I want in SQL:

```
Select *, st.StatusDescription from Product As p
Join Status As s On p.StatusId = s.Id
Join StatusTranslations As st on s.Id = st.StatusId
Where (...predicate...) And st.Language = 'en-US'
```

so that I can display the StatusDescription in my View:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of Product)
...
@For Each item In Model
    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Status.StatusTranslations.StatusDescription)
Next
```

In my view I receive the error:

> StatusDescription is not a member of ICollection(Of
>   StatusTranslations)

The question is, how should the vb.net query look like to achieve this and is a change in the database schema and/or view necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that filtered `Include` is not supported. I think in this case the easiest thing is to load the `Product`s and `Status`es first and then the translations. I'll show you how to do it in C#:

```cs
var products =  db.Products.Include(p => p.Status)
                  .AsExpandable()
                  .Where(predicate);
var translations = products
                  .Select(p => p.Status.StatusTranslations
                                .FirstOrDefault(tran => tran.Language == "en-Us"))
                  .Load();
```

Now in your view, you can do:

```cs
@For Each item In Model
    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Status.StatusTranslations
                                             .FirstOrDefault().StatusDescription)
Next
```

The two LINQ queries load the required data into the context. EF populates the navigation properties by *relationship fixup* so you can actually find `item.Status.StatusTranslations.FirstOrDefault()`.

One important thing: you have to disable lazy loading first:

```cs
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

This is because the navigation properties, even though they are populated, are not marked as loaded. Addressing them would otherwise still trigger lazy loading.